# angularJS + ionic. Could not resolve state from

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Hello i have diffrents states for 1 controller. that looks like this:

```
        .state('new-orders', {
        url: "/new-orders",
        templateUrl: "views/new-orders.html",
        controller: 'OrderCtrl',
        cache: false
    })

    .state('view-order', {
        url: "/view-order/:orderid",
        templateUrl: "views/view-order.html",
        controller: 'OrderCtrl',
        cache: false
    })

    .state('open-orders', {
        url: "/open-orders",
        templateUrl: "views/open-orders.html",
        controller: 'OrderCtrl',
        cache: false
    })

    .state('completed-orders', {
        url: "/completed-orders",
        templateUrl: "views/completed-orders.html",
        controller: 'OrderCtrl',
        cache: false
    });
```

now when a user is in state new-orders, a user can open a order. I do so using:

```
    $scope.goToOrder = function(orderid) {
    $state.go('view-order/:orderid/',{orderid:orderid});
    }
```

but for some reason when goToOrder is called i get this response:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'view-order/:orderid/' from state 'new-orders'
```

Answer (score 1):

$state.go accept a state name not a url.

Try this:

```
$scope.goToOrder = function(orderid) {
    $state.go('view-order',{orderid:orderid});
}
```